# Form level validation on multiple fields and custom error with Yup and react-hook-form

Tags: validation, testing, react-hook-form, yup

I currently have the following Yup validation schema with react-hook-form:

```
yup
  .object()
  .shape({
    source: yup.string().required(),
    featureType: yup.string().required(),
    table: yup.object({
      data: yup.array().of(
        yup.object({
          timestamp: yup.date().required(),
          mmsi: yup.string(),
          ircs: yup.string(),
          extMarking: yup.string(),
          name: yup.string(),
          flag: yup.string(),
          type: yup
            .string()
            .oneOf(TypeSelectOptions.map((opt) => opt.value))
            .required(),
          latitude: yup.string(),
          longitude: yup.string(),
          heading: yup.string(),
        })
      ),
    }),
    externalPositions: yup.object({
      active: yup.boolean(),
      radioButton: yup.string(),
      checkboxes: yup.array().of(
        yup.object({
          label: yup.string(),
          checked: yup.boolean(),
        })
      ),
    }),
  })
  .test({
    name: 'maxMmsi',
    test: function (form, { createError }) {
      if (
        form.externalPositions.active &&
        _.uniqBy(form.table.data, 'mmsi').length > 2
      )
        return createError({
          path: 'general',
          message: 'Importing is limited to a max of 10 distinct vesselss',
        })
      return true
    },
  })
```

This works 'fine'. However, the custom error is not created and I can't access and display the custom error that should be in `general` path